# How can get a heap dump direct from Android?

Tags: java, android

I just want to know how to get heap dump of my application direct from the device. I am already getting the heap dump from Eclipse memory analyzer (MAT) but it gives heap dump from emulator.

Please give me some links.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to get a heap dump when the application is running on an `actual` android device? Or from the JVM within the emulator?

Answer (score 8):

Step #1: Buy an Android device.

Step #2: Buy a USB cable to connect between the device and your development machine, if the device did not come with one.

Step #3: Enable USB debugging on the device (depending on Android OS version, this may be in "Developer Options" or in "Applications" in the Settings app)

Step #4: Plug the USB cable into the device and the development machine.

Step #5: Run your app on the device.

Step #6: In DDMS, click on your process in the Devices view, for the copy of your app running on your device.

Step #7: Click the "Dump HPROF File" icon in the Devices view's toolbar (looks like a half-filled can with a downward-pointing arrow)

In other words, you get a heap dump from a device in exactly the same way that you get a heap dump from the emulator, by choosing the process to dump and requesting the dump.

Comment: thanks.. it gives me help for optimizing memory.

Comment: That was amazing help,, Thank you for Step by Step Solution.

Comment: How do you do this programmatically in app code or even better how to do get an appium test to tell app to do a heap dump?

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi: By code, use [`dumpHprofData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData(java.lang.String)). I have never used Appium and so cannot comment on it, sorry.